# Adding css by jquery

Tags: jquery

I know how to add css by jquery .But I am thinking to do it other way.My approch

```
var alrt = 'width:200px;';

jQuery("#login").css(' + alrt + ');
```

Can I do this way?I have no output so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
var alrt = 'width:200px;';
jQuery("#login").attr("style", alrt);
```

If you want to copy across existing style:

```
var alrt = jQuery("#login").attr("style") + 'width:200px;';
jQuery("#login").attr("style", alrt);
```

Just be careful with that, using .css() is better since if the style is already set on an element then it will overwrite it whereas the above essentially concats strings together.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed.I want to take it a bit furthur.How can I ad d multiple style in this way? I mean "width:300px;color:red;"

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the css property and value as separate arguments to [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
jQuery("#login").css('width', '200px');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this `addClass` in jquery. please don't add css in inline style.

```
<style>
    addingWidth {
        width:200px;
    }
</style>
```

```
jQuery("#login").addClass("addingWidth");
```

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with inline styles. It's a complete waste of time to assign classes to temporary states of elements, and I don't think this is good at all. Seperating layout from content is good, but don't take it too far. Inline styles still work, and they're okay to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like this is css
    jQuery("#login").css({'width':'200px'});
You also try the attr

Answer (score 0):

you can add css in jquery in the following ways.

if you need to apply only one style in the css, you can add like this.

```
$("#login").css("width", "200px");
```

if you have to add multiple styles in the css, you can add like this.

```
$("#login")).css({"width-color": "200px", "font-size": "25px"});
```